# Improving execution time of this Python "angle-of-arrival" estimation algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, scipy

### Background

I've written a [python](/questions/tagged/python) implementation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4348433/822508) answer to my recent question over on Math SE. In short, the problem is as follows:

I have an experimental setup consisting of three *receivers*, with known rectangular coordinates `[xi, yi, zi]`, and a transmitter with *unknown* coordinates `[x,y,z]` emitting a signal at *unknown* time `t` with velocity `c` and arriving at receiver `i` at *known* time `ti`.

This information is insufficient to uniquely determine the rectangular coordinates of the transmitter. We *can*, however, estimate the angle to the transmitter (i.e. the transmitter's `phi` and `theta` in spherical coordinates). This may be done by solving the system of equations given in the linked post.

My goal is to solve these equations for real, experimental data.

---

### Problem

I have been able to write an effective [python](/questions/tagged/python) implementation of the approach described in the linked post. For both simulated and experimental data, this gives satisfactory estimates of the angle to the transmitter.

I now wish to use this in practice. Unfortunately, however, my code runs too slowly to be useful in my desired application.

Ideally, we'd like to be able to solve for on the order of 1 million datapoints per hour in
a near-real-time application. Currently, this takes several hours. While I recognize that, particularly with Python, dramatic performance improvements are not to be expected, any improvement would be helpful.

In short, I'd like to reduce the execution time of this algorithm. Due to the minimal Linux install (and my lack of control over it) being used on the host machine, I'd like to do so by improving my code, and without use of additional modules/external libraries/etc if possible.

---

### Code

```
import math
import numpy as np
import ROOT

from scipy.optimize import root
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ROOT import TFile, TNtuple

c = 299792


@dataclass
class Vertexer:

    roc: list

    def fun(self, var, dat):
        f0 = var.dot(self.roc[0] - self.roc[1]) - c * (dat[1] - dat[0])
        f1 = var.dot(self.roc[1] - self.roc[2]) - c * (dat[2] - dat[1])

        n = np.linalg.norm(var) - 1

        return [f0, f1, n]

    def find(self, dat):
        result = root(
            self.fun,
            (0, 0, 0),
            method="lm",
            args=dat,
            options={
                "col_deriv": 1,
                "xtol": 1.49012e-08,
                "ftol": 1.49012e-08,
                "gtol": 0.0,
                "maxiter": 0,
                "eps": 0.0,
                "factor": 100,
                "diag": None,
            },
        )
        if result.success:
            return result.x


def main():
    myVertexer = Vertexer(
        [
            np.array([3.0085470085470085, 3.7642857142857116, -0.06]),
            np.array([2.0034188034188034, 2.0142857142857133, -0.19]),
            np.array([1.0324786324786326, 0.27142857142857135, -0.19]),
        ]
    )

    data = ROOT.RDataFrame("D", "2018_filtered.root")
    colns = data.AsNumpy(columns=["ai", "aj", "ak"])

    f = TFile("theta_phi_2.root", "RECREATE")
    ntuple = TNtuple("N", "N", "i:j:k:ai:aj:ak")

    for (ai, aj, ak) in zip(colns["ai"], colns["aj"], colns["ak"]):

        v = myVertexer.find([ai, aj, ak])

        if v.any() != None:
            ntuple.Fill(v[0], v[1], v[2], ai, aj, ak)

    ntuple.Write()
    f.Write()


main()
```

---

### Step-Through

The `Vertexer` class contains a fairly standard and straightforward `SciPy` based system of equations solution "algorithm". The function `func()` contains the system of equations described in the linked post, and `find()` solves the system given the times of arrival (`dat`) and the receiver coordinates (`roc`, provided upon instantiation). I'm using a *Levenberg Marquardt* solver with `coln_deriv` set to `True` in order to improve solution speed. I see similar solution accuracy across all solvers. All other settings are set to default.

The `main()` function reads time-of-arrival data from a `.root` file ([see](http://root.cern.ch)) into a `dict` of NumPy arrays, which I loop over, feed to the algorithm, and record the result in another `.root` file.

---

If you like, you may replace the `main()` function with the following crude "source simulation" code I've written, which simply produces a random point, computes the arrival time of a signal from that point to three randomly-placed "receivers", and feeds those times to the algorithm:

```
        x0 = random.randrange(0,1000); y0 = random.randrange(0,1000); z0 = random.randrange(0,1000)

        x1 = random.randrange(0,50); x2 = random.randrange(0,50); x3 = random.randrange(0,50);
        y1 = random.randrange(0,50); y2 = random.randrange(0,50); y3 = random.randrange(0,50);
        z1 = random.randrange(0,50); z2 = random.randrange(0,50); z3 = random.randrange(0,50);

        t1 = math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2 + (y0-y1)**2 + (z0-z1)**2)/c
        t2 = math.sqrt((x0-x2)**2 + (y0-y2)**2 + (z0-z2)**2)/c
        t3 = math.sqrt((x0-x3)**2 + (y0-y3)**2 + (z0-z3)**2)/c

        myVertexer = Vertexer([[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], [x3,y3,z3]])
        result = myVertexer.find([t1,t2,t3])
```

Comment: I see you used what I suggested in the comments to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617656/solving-this-rectangular-nonlinear-system-with-scipy).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your equations analytically rather than numerically (probably someone will say that this is not the place for this).

Let's analyze your function

```py
    def fun(self, var, dat):
        f0 = var.dot(self.roc[0] - self.roc[1]) - c * (dat[1] - dat[0])
        f1 = var.dot(self.roc[1] - self.roc[2]) - c * (dat[2] - dat[1])
        n = np.linalg.norm(var) - 1

        return [f0, f1, n]
```

The solutions of `f0 = 0` lie in a plane normal to `self.roc[0] - self.roc[1]`.

The solutions of `f1 = 0` lie in a plane normal to `self.roc[1] - self.roc[2]`.

The solutions of `n = 0` lies in a sphere.

The intersection of two planes is a line going on the direction give by the cross product between the normal of the two planes.

The intersection between a line and a sphere will either be (a) one tangent point; (b) two points, one entering, one leaving the sphere; (c) no solution if the line passes is far from the sphere.